# How to get source IP from a Pod in kubernetes?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have set up a working k8s cluster.

Each node of the cluster is inside network 10.11.12.0/24 (physical network). Over this network is running a flanneld (canal) cni.

Each node has another network interface (not managed by k8s) with cidr 192.168.0.0/24

When I deploy a service like:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-awesome-webapp
spec:
  selector:
    server: serverA
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.0.163
```

The service is accessible at http://192.168.0.163, but the Pod receives  source ip: 192.168.0.163 eth0 address of the server: not my source ip (192.168.0.94).

Deployment consists of 2 pods with the same spec.

Is possible to Pods to view my source ip m? 
Anyone knows how to manage it? `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` seems not working.

Comment: I believe the source ip should be available on the `x_forwarded_for` header of the request

Comment: At TCP level is impossible to manipulate L7 headers i think. Should be a Ingress?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes change the source IP with the cluster/node IPs for which the details information can be found on [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/). Kubernetes has a feature to [preserve the client source IP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/#preserving-the-client-source-ip) which I believe you already are already aware. 
Seems like a this is a bug in Kubernetes and there is already [an open bug](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52096) for this issue of below command not working properly.

> externalTrafficPolicy: Local

I suggest to post on the bug to get more attention on the issue.